# How can I drain a lake of Xenomass?

Tags: civilization-beyond-earth

For the quest Cultural Burden, I have been tasked to "Drain the Xenomass lake at

> the crash site."

However, I've no idea how to do that.  Any improvement a worker can apply produces a warning that doing so will fail the quest, as does attempting to

> build an expedition.

What must I do to progress in this quest?

Comment: Not surprised to see this question, its one of the most annoying things in the game. The game even has a recommended action implemented but it recommends the action that fails the quest.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to the Xenomass lake using any unit. There will be an additional button on the unit's actions bar, labeled "Drain Xenomass". It's on the right end of the bar and looks like a puddle of bubbling liquid.

Comment: Oh, does that work with any unit? I used a worker to drain it for quest credit, didn't realize other units would work. I do know an explorer doesn't work :-P

Comment: an explorer can drain the lake